# Java spliting text document using delimeter

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, delimiter, split

I am reading a text file and I want content of that text file to split it in lines at the end of each sentence, that means at dot character ".". My code so far is:

```
    String content = new Scanner(new File("src//text.txt")).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
    //System.out.println(content);
    String[] myString = content.split("\\. ");
    for (int i =0; i < myString.length ; i++)           
    System.out.println(myString[i]);
```

It prints the content in lines, but if the content of that text file has a new line new paragraph it prints for me 2 lines, my point is that I don't want that content to have blank lines in between.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `"\\.\\s+"`. This will consume all the whitespace after a dot.

Comment: thnx Roland Illig that's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
CharSequence fileContent = new IOUtils.toString(new FileInputStream("file"));  
List<String> sentences = Splitter.on('.').trimResults().splitToList(fileContent);
```